# Google Drive for iOS API in Swift: File uploads not working

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use the Google Drive for iOS API to upload a file from my app. However, the upload doesn't seem to finish, ever, even with an error. In fact, my uploadProgressBlock is not even being called, so I suspect it is not starting.

My class properties:

```
let kKeychainItemName = "Drive API"
let kClientID = "*******"
let kClientSecret = "*****"
let scopes = [kGTLAuthScopeDrive]
let service = GTLServiceDrive()
```

Here is the authentication code:

```
//Google Drive authentication initialization
    service.authorizer = GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.authForGoogleFromKeychainForName(
        kKeychainItemName,
        clientID: kClientID,
        clientSecret: kClientSecret
    )
```

And here is the upload code (I'm only doing a test file right now):

```
    let title = "Hello.txt"
    let content = "hello world"
    let mimeType = "text/plain"
    let metaData = GTLDriveFile()
    metaData.title = title
    let data = content.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
    let uP = GTLUploadParameters(data: data!, MIMEType: mimeType)
    let query = GTLQueryDrive.queryForFilesInsertWithObject(metaData, uploadParameters: uP)

    let serviceTicket = service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: {(ticket, file, error) -> Void in

        println("complete")


    })

    serviceTicket.uploadProgressBlock = {(ticket, written, total) in


        println("making progress")

    }
```

As you can see most of my code is similar to Google's quickstart guide. Also, the app authenticates properly.

Comment: Can you provide any logs from the execution of your code? Are the parameter data set correctly for the GTLUploadParameters? I think this parameter needs to be declared as 'uploadParametersWithData', and you need to specify the data type for 'metaData', in queryForFilesInsertWithObject

Comment: You might be interested in this repo: https://github.com/goktugyil/QorumLogs

Comment: There is a working example [here](https://github.com/baby03201/iOS-Swift-GoogleDriveSample), but you may need to convert code to swift 2.0