# Type 'GTLQueryDrive' has no member 'queryForFilesInsertWithObject'

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api

I am writing code in swift.I was trying to integrate google drive using the below link https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart. i downloaded the google client library using link https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client.git which is mentioned in step 2 of google's developer guide. i am able to run the example code here successfully. but i have to upload file to google drive. so i am using queryForFilesInsertWithObject method. but i am getting error  **GTLQueryDrive' has no member 'queryForFilesInsertWithObject'**.my sample code is below:

```
  func uploadPhoto(image: UIImage) {
    print("uploading Photo")
    let dateFormat  = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormat.dateFormat = "'Quickstart Uploaded File ('EEEE MMMM d, YYYY h:mm a, zzz')"

    let file = GTLDriveFile() as GTLDriveFile
    //file.title = dateFormat.stringFromDate(NSDate())
    file.descriptionProperty = "Uploaded from Google Drive IOS"
    file.mimeType = "image/png"

    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    let uploadParameters = GTLUploadParameters(data: data!, MIMEType: file.mimeType)
    let query = GTLQueryDrive.queryForFilesInsertWithObject(file, uploadParameters: uploadParameters) as! GTLQueryDrive
    //let waitIndicator = self.showWaitIndicator("Uploading To Google Drive")

    self.service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler:  { (ticket, insertedFile , error) -> Void in
        let myFile = insertedFile as? GTLDriveFile

       // waitIndicator.dismissWithClickedButtonIndex(0, animated: true)
        if error == nil {
            print("File ID \(myFile?.identifier)")
            self.showAlert("Google Drive", message: "File Saved")
        } else {
            print("An Error Occurred! \(error)")
            self.showAlert("Google Drive", message: "Sorry, an error occurred!")
        }

    })
}
```

please help me if any project is available?

Comment: I think you could refer to this [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864920/google-drive-for-ios-api-in-swift-file-uploads-not-working?rq=1), the OP have encountered the same issue with uploading files.

Answer (score 3):

Use

let query = GTLQueryDrive.queryForFilesCreateWithObject(file, uploadParameters: uploadParameters) as GTLQueryDrive

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesCreateWithObject:metadata                                                uploadParameters:uploadParameters];`